# Using variable in where clause

Tags: php, laravel

Right now I have this defined in **app/routes.php**:

```
View::share('user_image_count', Items::where('user_id', '=', 1)->count());
```

It returns the number `9`, just what I want.

I would like to make this dynamic so it is based on the user_id of the user that is logged in/authenticated.

I currently use this in my views:

```
{{ Auth::user()->user_id }}
```

How can I adjust my query in routes.php so that it uses the authenticated user's id number?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the following?

```
if (Auth::check())
{
    $user_id     = Auth::user()->user_id;
    $items_count = Items::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->count();

    View::share('user_image_count', $items_count);
}
```

I believe it should work.

Comment: what happens when the current user isn't authed ?

Comment: It will probably give an error, so better put an if($user_id != null) around it.

Comment: Good catch @lagbox! As Mathias mentioned, it would be better to check before using it.

Comment: This returns the total number of rows in the `Items` table. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
View::share('user_image_count', function(){
    return Auth::check() ? 
           Items::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->user_id)->count() : '';
});
```

In your view:

```
{{ $user_image_count() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can better do this with an helper class .

let's say helper as class

```
 class Helper{
   public static function GetUserCount($user_id){

       return View::share('user_image_count', Items::where('user_id',$user_id)->count());

   }
```

}

and in you view call this class and pass user_id to it

```
Echo this in view {{Helpers::GetUserCount(Auth::user()->user_id)}}
```

So this way it would be dynamic for all logined user